# ImportError: No module named 'spm1d

Tags: python-3.x, matlab-spm

I have Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)) on my Mac laptop and I am facing this problem:

```
import spm1d
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named 'spm1d'
```

I searched about the problem and I did not find any solution.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the module (spm1d) is not installed, you have to install the module before import, open terminal bash run the command:
easy_install spm1d

or you can refer to the official document below for more detail:
http://www.spm1d.org/install/InstallationPython.html

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Tiny.D. I tried conda install -c melund spm1d=0.3.1.4 and it worked.